# sed.exe expression in bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, sed

I am using the Windows port of `sed.exe`.

When I do something like that directly from the command line:

```
sed.exe -i "s/WRITE;/WRITE; TRUNCATE TABLE `Team_matchdayResults`;/g" my_script.sql
```

everything works flawlessly and the text parts are changed in the `my_script.sql` file.

Now I want to do exactly the same but from within a `.bat` file. What I know is that I have to escape double quotes there, so I did it like that.

```
sed.exe -i ""s/WRITE;/WRITE; TRUNCATE TABLE `Team_matchdayResults`;/g"" my_file.sql
```

Unfortunately this ends with the following error

```
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

I suppose that I have to escape something more but I seem to have no idea what exactly. I have read somewhere that `;` should be escaped in a batch file but only in `FOR` loop. However this has not brought me any further.

What do I have to escape more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded [GNU Sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) just to test this and I found out you don't need to escape anything for it to work inside a `.bat` file. Quotes `"` and their contents are interpreted correctly.

`test.txt` contents:

```
Test0 WRITE;
Test1 WRITE
Test2 WRITE;
```

`test.bat` contents:

```
sed -i "s/WRITE;/WRITE; TRUNCATE TABLE `Team_matchdayResults`;/g" test.txt
```

New contents of `test.txt`, after running `test.bat`:

```
Test0 WRITE; TRUNCATE TABLE `Team_matchdayResults`;
Test1 WRITE
Test2 WRITE; TRUNCATE TABLE `Team_matchdayResults`;
```

---

Did you try out [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org)? It allows running and scripting common UNIX commands on Windows.

Comment: You are right. I was escaping double quotes, because I did so in the past. Frankly said, no idea why... I know Cygwin, but in this case, I am not allowed to install it.